# How many direct quotes are there from previous films?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

There are an extraordinary number of quotes from previous *Star Wars* films in *The Rise of Skywalker*.

> Palpatine

is a particularly heavy offender, saying, among other things, that "the dark side of the force is a pathway to many abilities" and that "the time has come." But other characters say lines from previous films, including the obligatory "I have a bad feeling about this."

Which lines in the film were taken line-for-line from previous films in the trilogy?

Comment: All of Leia's came from unused *Force Awakens* footage, for a start.

Comment: Probably not enough to warrant an answer as its an action rather than words, but I'm pretty sure Ben mirrors a shrug Han made in ROTJ, when outnumbered...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well if it was unused it is not quite what I mean.

Comment: Just a rhetorical question, why do we put Palpatine's name in spoilers across SciFi? He is confirmed multiple times, he is in the teaser poster and on the trailers.

Comment: @Lefteris008: some of us intentionally don't look and posters and don't watch trailers, because we like to watch movies, not watch a couple of hundred seconds of a movie and hear some descriptions and then eventually watch the rest with our experience coloured by distracting expectations.

Comment: So you are telling me that you didn't know Palpatine was at that film?

Comment: @Lefteris008 : I didn't, until I was in the theater watching the movie.  So, yeah, it is certainly possible to not know a major detail like that ahead of time. 
 Actually, one of the main reasons I chose to watch the movie when I did, instead of later, is I noticed a Stack Exchange question about the movie, so I wanted to hurry up and watch the movie before I get accidentally exposed to any spoilers.

Answer (score 2):

The Han memory(?) says "I know." like the real Han said in *The Empire Strikes Back* and Leia said in *Return of the Jedi*.

Luke says "There’s something my sister would have wanted you to have" in regards to a lightsaber, similar to Obi-Wan's “Your father wanted you to have this when you were old enough” in *A New Hope*.

As mentioned in the question, Palpatine repeats his lines of "The dark side of the force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural" and "the time has come," both from *Revenge of the Sith*.

Lando says "I got a bad feeling about this" a variant on a [phrase said across the franchise](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/I_have_a_bad_feeling_about_this).

Finally, Obi-Wan's ghost's line of "These are your final steps, Rey. Rise and take them... Rey... Rise." takes some dialogue from the Original Trilogy, though it is edited into something new.